# MessageBox.Show not showing when inside an async method when debugging

Tags: silverlight

In debugging an app, I came across some odd behavior with MessageBox.Show not showing.  To reproduce, use the following and run it.

It will work as expected, showing the messageboxes.

Now put a breakpoint in DoSomething and run.  The MessageBoxes will not be shown!

Now remove the async keyword and it works as expected again.

What is up with this?  I have an app that does the usual confirm dialogs, but they were being skipped during debugging. I finally traced it to the async keyword, but this doesn't make any sense to me as to why it occurs.  Maybe is a bug in the debugger.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       DoSomething();
    }

    public async void DoSomething() {
        MessageBox.Show("Starting");
        ShowMessageBox();
        MessageBox.Show("In DoSomething()");


    }

    public void ShowMessageBox() {
        MessageBox.Show("In ShowMessageBox");
    }
```

Comment: Where is the completed event for your async method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Visual Studio.